# IE11 Windows 7 Print issue after kb4021558

Tags: internet-explorer-11

Apologies for the slightly vague question but I'm pulling my hair out.  Since this update we have had numerous calls regarding printing from our web app.  Our web app uses an iframe and we use css @media print to hide all but this iframe for printing purposes.  Since the update the user receives an Error 404--Not Found instead of the actual page.  It would seem from the network trace that IE creates a temp .htm file in the local directory like D3CD911.htm, it then downloads css/js resources and then finally it makes this call /D3CD911.htm.  This is making a call to www.mywebsite.co.uk/D3CD911.htm.  This obviously does not exist on the website so the 404 is returned.
I struggling to find a pattern to the problem and it doesn't seem to be affecting other public sites.  I think the issue is with window.print() method.  I can semi reproduce it here at https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/printer.xhtml. If you click the print button you will get the error. Although this is using the jqprint javascript function if you then use the browser print button it also fails.

Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Update:
Microsoft have now released a patch: [Microsoft IE patch](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4032782/a-blank-page-or-404-error-prints-when-you-try-to-print-a-frame-in-inte)

Just wanted to summarise the workarounds I've found and which have been posted here.

1) If you are using your own print button change to use `document.execCommand('print', false, null);`.  Test support using `document.queryCommandSupported('print')` and call `window.print()` if not supported (Prob just Firefox)

2) Use Print Preview.  Additionally select the part of the page to print, right click and select print preview. Then select `As selected on screen`.

3) Use another browser like Chrome

4) Uninstall the update

5) Wait for Microsoft fix. Their KB page [KB Link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4021558/cumulative-security-update-for-internet-explorer-june-13-2017) has been updated with this as a known issue. Therefore you assume a fix is on the way.

Comment: Do you know if there is a patch for Windows 10?

Comment: Not sure. Did see in another forum someone said towards the end of the month.

Comment: Note:  "patch" being "remove security update" though

Comment: @Bobcat88 Looks like they have fixes ready for Windows 10; check out my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44804886/225906

Answer (score 13):

andyfinch, you're a genius!  The following code appears to work for a print button contained within a frame:

```
function Print() {
  if (document.queryCommandSupported('print')) {
    document.execCommand('print', false, null);
  }
  else {
    window.parent.<framename>.focus();
    window.print();
  }
}
```

Comment: This only prints a small visible portion of the iframe for me.  Copy and paste into a separate document is the only workaround ive found so far.

Answer (score 7):

andyfinch's workaround is also working for us. Thanks Andy!

MS has flagged this issue with "WON'T FIX" (6/15/17): https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/12349663/ Update: that flag might just indicate that it's not an issue with MS Edge so it won't get fixed by the Edge developers.

Installing KB4021558 breaks printing from our website (the pages are blank, the footer shows some variant of "res://ieframe.dll/i273gyew.htm"). Uninstalling it restores printing functionality.

KB4021558 is also included in KB4022719, KB4022725 and KB4022727.

Comment: The "edge" team has posted "no fix" but the actual MS KB has a known error section acknowledging (with no workaround):  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4021558/cumulative-security-update-for-internet-explorer-june-13-2017

Answer (score 2):

I found a workaround:  if the iframe you're trying to print is visible, right click on it and choose Print preview... instead of Print... from the context menu.  The preview seems to be printable (but may show only part of the frame contents).

Also, for the record, the problematic 64-bit Win7 update is KB4022719.

Comment: Yes I found this too.  Also I think problem may be related to `window.print()`.  This has the same issue as clicking the print button, however if i run `document.execCommand('print', false, null)` I think it works. Will be testing this properly in the morning.

Comment: @andyfinch, your solution is working for IE11. Too bad that I need to support multi browsers. Anyway thanks to you for the workaround.

Comment: You can test support with `document.queryCommandSupported('print')`.  If not supported just run the normal `window.print()`

Answer (score 2):

MS released updates yesterday (June 27th) that address it for Windows 10:

> This non-security update includes quality improvements. No new
>   operating system features are being introduced in this update. Key
>   changes include:
>
> • Addressed an issue introduced by KB4022715 where Internet Explorer
>   and Microsoft Edge printing from a frame may result in 404 not found
>   or blank page printed.

**Links:**

Windows 10 (Initial Release - Build 10240)

[KB4032695 - Build 10240.17446](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4032695)

Windows 10 Version 1511 (Initial Release - Build 10586)

[KB4032693- Build 10586.965](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4032693)

Windows 10 Version 1607 (Initial Release - Build 14393)

[KB4022723 - Build 14393.1378](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4022723)

Windows 10 Version 1703 (Initial Release - Build 15063)

[KB4022716 - Build 15063.447](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4022716)

**[Source/More info](http://winsupersite.com/windows-10/june-2017-end-month-cumulative-patches-windows-10-addresses-over-60-issues)**

I grabbed them from the [Windows Update Catalog](http://catalog.update.microsoft.com) today, to use with WSUS.

Answer (score 1):

Heres the workaround I have been using for this in IE 11:

1. Right click frame and choose select all, or [ctrl + A] in the frame
2. Right click and choose print preview
3. There should be an option in your preview for "As selected on screen". Choosing this allowed me to print everything in the frame.

Answer (score 0):

We were having multiple frames in the print screen and calling `document.execCommand('print', false, null);` could not fix our issue. Instead `window.parent[frameName].document.execCommand('print', false, null);` fixed it.

Comment: Yes `document` has to refer to the specific DOM `document`