# res:/iefram.dll print blank pages

Tags: internet-explorer, sharepoint, printing, system, internet-explorer-11

I have very strage problem...
Im using Win 7, IE11.
When I try to print from a list in SharePoint platform, the print becomes blank page, with the footer "res://ieframe.dll/(something).htm
When I try to print from another page which it not list in the same site, it printed successfuly, with the footer of the URL of the site.

When another users try to print the same list in SP, they can print it successfuly.

I had tried reset IE11,Windows updates, delete %temp% etc...

someone have an idea ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug in the latest Windows security update that only affects printing from iframes in IE (presumably what Sharepoint is doing).  Not everyone has the update yet, so not everyone is affected.

See this question for more details:  [IE11 Windows 7 Print issue after kb4021558](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44547861/ie11-windows-7-print-issue-after-kb4021558)

Comment: Right !!!!

Thank you very much !