# Cannot print iframes in ie 11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, iframe, error-handling, internet-explorer-11

I have a webpage with a bunch of iframes I am trying to print. IE 11 has a known error printing iframes that has tried to be resolved before on here. I cannot resolve my issue though. Here is the javascript to print all the frames:

```
function printall() {
  window.print();
  for (var i=0; i<window.frames.length; i++) {
    alert('Click here AFTER you have sent document ' + (i+1) + ' to the 
printer.');
    window.frames[i].focus();
    window.frames[i].print();
  }
}
```

refernce to other thread: [IE11 Windows 7 Print issue after kb4021558](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44547861/ie11-windows-7-print-issue-after-kb4021558)

Comment: What are you printning exactly?

Comment: These six frames. All 1100 width and 800 height:                                    <iframe name="mapassessor" src="http://maps.assessor.lacounty.gov"></iframe>
<iframe name="pictoaerial" src="https://explorer.pictometry.com/login.php"></iframe>
<iframe name="pictooblique" src="https://explorer.pictometry.com/login.php"></iframe>
<iframe id="street" class="zoom" name="street" src="http://localhost/streetview.html"></iframe>
<iframe name="portal" src="http://10.168.22.139/"></iframe>
<iframe name="parcelmap" src="http://maps.assessor.lacounty.gov"></iframe>

Answer (score 0):

I've tried your code and it seems work well in IE.

I'm sorry that I'm confused about the issue you meet.

You could see my running result in IE11.

[image: before print]

[image: print result]

Comment: Are you able to save a pdf in IE 11? I cannot. I get the error "There wan an error processing a page. There was a problem reading this document (109).